# VueJs insert array of data in LocalStorage using push

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, local-storage, back

to explain my problem, I want to make a little game where we have to click as many times as possible on a point during a given time. The problem is that I would like to make a list that would display all the old results. I show you world code for this... (update with JSON)

My VueJs (front) :

```
<div class="resultat">
   <p v-for="resultat in resultats" :key="resultat">{{ resultat}}</p>
</div>
```

My VueJs (back) :

```
data() {
    return {
      clique: 0,
      resultats: [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultat"))],
    };
  },
methods: {
onTimesUp() {
    this.resultats.push(this.clique)
    localStorage.setItem("resultat", JSON.stringify(this.resultats));
  }
}
```

The result after 4 try is : [ [ [ [ null, 6 ], 7 ], 3 ], 5 ]

And I would like : [6, 7, 3, 5]

Please help me I try since 2 days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is your storing an array of items, but then onload your placing the array in an array: `resultats: [JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultat"))],`

Remove the wrapping `[` and `]`.

Though personally, is nicer to keep data clean as a declaration than use a before rendering lifecycle hook to populate it, i.e created, beforeMount.

Also on initial load with no scores `localStorage.getItem("resultat")` will return null, causing your array to become, null. Do a check on it or simply do `|| '[]'`

```
  data() {
    return {
      clique: 0,
      resultats: []
    };
  },
  created() {
     this.resultats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultat") || '[]')
  },
  methods: {
    onTimesUp() {
      this.resultats.push(this.clique)
      localStorage.setItem("resultat", JSON.stringify(this.resultats));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store it as a string, so you need to store it using JSON (JSON is a way to serialize/deserialize Javascript data to strings):

`localStorage.setItem("resultat", JSON.stringify(this.resultats) );`

and

`message: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("resultat")),`

See here for more on JSON: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp

Comment: OOOOh yeaah thanks you ! But now the result after 3 try is : [ { "message": [ { "message": [ { "message": null }, { "message": 6 } ] }, { "message": 6 } ] }, { "message": 3 } ]

Comment: I think it’s because I send the table has q times so the table goes into the table etc...